# Adding option group check box in word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-office

I am working on a Form designed in Word 2007. I have Yes or No CheckBox. I added the checkbox through Developer Ribbon. CheckBox allows the user to select both Yes and No. However, our condition is to allow the user to select either Yes or No.

To handle the scenario.I added a condition in the Macro to validate either ChkYes is True or False. Below is my syntax which is throwing an error as follows

" run time error : 5941 The requested member of the collection does not exist. "

```
Sub Macro1()

  Application.Run MacroName:="isChecked"
End Sub

Sub isChecked()

If ActiveDocument.FormFields("ChkYes").CheckBox.Value = True Then
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("ChkNo").CheckBox.Value = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how do you select both yes and no at the same time in a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for [allow one checkbox out of a group](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-do-you-allow-only-one-check-box-out-of-a-group/4c413b3e-07eb-4abd-8378-053f5fd3f6b1?auth=1)

assign the following code as the Entry macro for all of the checkboxes, and protect the form. The Check Box Form Fields in each Frame will then be mutually exclusive.

```
Sub MakeCheckBoxesExclusive()

Dim oField As FormField

For Each oField In Selection.Frames(1).Range.FormFields
    oField.CheckBox.Value = False
Next oField

Selection.FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True

End Sub
```

There is one minor but unfortunate drawback to doing this; if the user tabs or uses their keyboard arrow keys to go from one form field to the next, each checkbox form field will become selected, in turn, as they reach it (and the others will be deselected); so they have to use the mouse, not the keyboard, to select the checkboxes .

Comment: Thanks.. But i am still getting the 5941 - Requested Member of the collection does not exist. I tested the check box...and it allows me to select both the checkbox

Comment: We do have other check boxes in the form. However, we are focusing only on this Yes or No Check Box. We are just avoiding to use option button. If we cant implement check box for yes or no,we will have to go with Option Button..

Comment: Did you try radio button? Radio buttons are mutually exclusive, they'll get your job done.

Comment: Yes please.. Radio button is working .. no doubt on  that.. but want to give a try with check box functionality

Comment: Thanks.. Option button is helpful for Yes or No.  Selecting one check box from multiple checkbox, we still need this macro to be working.